# Symfony - JMS Serializer - Convert a datetime to a specific timezone when serializing

Tags: symfony, datetime, timezone, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity that stores a datetime, and I use the JMSSerializer in order to return this field through an API:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'d/m - H:i', 'Europe/Paris'>")
 */
private $creationDateTime;
```

Into the database, the creationDateTime is stored with the UTC timezone.

Changing the format is correctly applied to the JSON API response (for instance, replacing "d/m H:i by d/m/Y H:i"), but the returned time is always the stored one (UTC one) and not the expected one (Europe/Paris) even if I set a totally different timezone.

For example, if the stored time is 15:04, the serialized time returned by the API is still 15:04 (UTC) and not the expected one (16:04, Europe/Paris).

Is there any way to apply the timezone on the stored date when serializing the response ?

Thanks in advance.

I use:
Symfony 4, JMS-SerializerBundle 3.1.0, JMS-Serializer 2.1.0

EDIT:

Here the walk-around I made, but definitely not the best way to solve this issue:

```
/**
 * Returns the signal creation date and time
 *
 * @Serializer\Type(
 *     "DateTime<'d/m/Y H:i'>"
 * )
 *
 * @Serializer\Groups({"signals"})
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
 * @Serializer\Expose
 */
public function getCreationDateTime(): \DateTime
{
    $dateTime = $this->creationDateTime;
    $dateTime->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));

    return $dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make it global is to configure it in:

**config > packages > jms_serializer.yaml**

like this:

```
jms_serializer:
    handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP" # ATOM
            default_timezone: "UTC" # defaults to whatever timezone set in php.ini or via date_default_timezone_set
```

See doc, [Extensions Reference](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration) part

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's a solution yes, but adding an annotation directly at the attribute level with the expected timezone should work too and handle the conversion, or am I missing something ?